Window VM with disk partition passthrough having issues
I have created a win 11 VM on gentoo linux host.
I have passed through a disk partition from HDD to the VM using virtio drivers.
Disk is always at a 100% in the VM, and opening file manager takes more than 10 mins. The VM is very unresponsive. This is very unusual performance for virtio drivers on HDD.
Disk layout on the host,
NVME - linux host
HDD Part 1 - linux host
HDD Part 2 - win 11 vm (using virtio and installed the relevant drivers on windows)
How do I fix this?
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source dev='/dev/disk/by-partuuid/9303a54f-de85-49d3-a3ba-9da8397120c7'/>
      <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      <boot order='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>

Attaching the vm full xml config here
EDIT (Aug 11th 2024):

I have a temporary fix, by not using /dev/disk/* paths to specify the source dev field in the xml config instead just direct mentioning the /dev/sda2 device. This helped improve the virtio disk performance significantly compared to the previous, but not to the expected limit. I still observe load times to be 4-5 secs to open settings or file explorer every time. The disk usage is still 100% all the time.
I changes the driver to SATA and that improved the performance compared to virtio but still a huge visible lag is observed in opening basic applications. The lag is huge when running gaming applications. The disk usage is again 100% all the time.
I also tried iothreadpin and allocated cores 0 and 4 to one io-thread. But that did give any performance improvement.
By performance improvement, I refer to load time of basic applications such as settings, file explorer, etc., when the internet is disabled and no other major applications are running on windows that can cause heavy disk usage.

Updated disk xml config:
<disk type="block" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" io="native" discard="unmap"/>
  <source dev="/dev/sda2"/>
  <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
</disk>

Disk-Usage Numbers (with the updated xml config):

Virtio

Read and write operations together : 10-15 MB/s
Only Read or Only Write : 15-20 MB/s


SATA

Read and write operations together : 40-50 MB/s
Only read or write operations : 50-60 MB/s



Based on the above observations,
I have the following questions,

Why is the virtio driver so slow compared to SATA? (virtio is preferred and suggested over any other driver in all the communities that discuss about disk passthrough.)
Is there a way to increase the performance of the disk partition passthrough when using the SATA driver?


You should not passthrough a partition but the entire device. If you use the same disk for hypervisor and VM use ordinary disk image files.

@paladin that's pretty much FUD; other than the case of SCSI passthrough (virtio-scsi + scsi-block), the only difference between a full drive and a partition is really just the "LBA scope size". I mean like in both cases they are nothing but ranges of logical blocks.

Ranges of logical blocks on the same device, which is shared between operating systems from which at least 1 doesn't know that this is a shared devices.

@paladin You would be "sharing" a block device in that sense anyway regardless of whether it is a partition. The only way you won't is passing through an HBA. (Not even "SCSI passthrough" would unbind/detach a block device from the host in any sense.) (It's not even really "passthrough" in any sense, but just "raw access".)

@TomYan No, passing through a full device via ‘raw’ access will not really share anything, unlike passing through a partition but using the rest of the device for the host. The host may do caching, may do readahead, and may do IO scheduling, but that’s it. And you can turn all of that off pretty easily on any Linux host.

@AustinHemmelgarn The device node will not be gone from the host even when you pass the full drive to qemu, and qemu will not stop the host from being able to access it in anyway. I used to pass the system drive of the host to a VM running Windows (which will not touch the partitions of the host because of their type GUID). virtio does NOT mean "passing through the device to the VM". Only virtio-scsi + scsi-block means "SCSI commands from the VM are "passed through" to the device".

@AustinHemmelgarn Also, when you aren't using scsi-block, qemu would/could literally just issue block I/O instructed by the guest like dd or similar userspace application (whereas when you use scsi-block, it will issue/pass SCSI commands, which means the block layer on the host side is bypassed, and it cannot be used with NVMe drive since there's no translation layer in the kernel like the case of ATA drive, at least not anymore). (What virtio does is just eliminating some protocol emulations and "unnecessary" extra translation work needed for that.)

@TomYan You seem to both completely misunderstand how QEMU’s block interface works (SCSI pass-through only skips the host block layer completely if you pass through the HBA, and NVMe drives can in fact be passed through directly to QEMU at least three different ways), and what resource sharing means. The fact that the host ‘could’ access a given block device does not mean the host is inherently sharing resources, it just means that sharing is possible. But unless you go out of your way to do stupid things, a raw disk passed directly to QEMU is not at all shared.

@AustinHemmelgarn That's what I'm talking about -- there's no logical relation between what you passed to qemu and whether the drive is shared. If you pass through an HBA, it's not SCSI passthrough, it'd be PCIe passthrough (unless your HBA is not connected via PCIe). Take a look at what scsi-block is before saying I misunderstood, because what I have been talking about is exactly that when you are not using that, qemu will access the drive via the host block layer, hence there's no "exclusive mode" or "passthrough" magic, hence it is shared.

@AustinHemmelgarn and as I said, even when you use scsi-block, it is still shared, because what it does is allow "SCSI passthrough" -- allowing the SCSI device to receive the SCSI command from the guest (via something called SG_IO, I believe, which is what hdparm or so also leverages). Only when you PCIe pass through an HBA (e.g. a SCSI host controller, not a SCSI drive; or an NVMe drive because of its "architecture"), the drive(s) will be more or less detached from the host, hence not shared.

@AustinHemmelgarn As a comparison, you can take a look at how "USB passthrough" (usb-host) works in qemu. The USB device would literally be unbound from its original driver in the host and bound by a driver that is for the passthrough. IMO that's the least that is needed for one to say a device is passed through and not shared by the host. (Although it reality, it does not expose stuff like UAS to the guest according to my past experience, so it's kind of a "lame passthrough" to me.)

Recommended alternative configuration, if you want to stick with direct passthrough:
<disk type="block" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="writethrough" error_policy="report" io="io_uring" ats="on"/>
  <source dev="/dev/sda2"/>
  <target dev="vdb" bus="virtio"/>
</disk>

Explanation of the changes:

Completely disabling the device cache will actually tank performance for the VM in a majority of cases, especially for writes, and especially for raw device passthrough. Enabling writethrough caching host-side should get you a significant performance boost without running the risks associated with writeback caching (which are the main reason to want to disable caching host-side).
Explicitly passing read and write errors up to the VM is exceedingly importent for a VM expected to be used for ‘regular usage’. Unless you have a very, very good reason to not do so (and you will know if you do), you should always have error_policy="report" on your disks.
The native IO backend for QEMU uses Linux’s AIO functionality. This has known performance issues, and in fact will in some cases be outperformed even by the threads backend. io_uring will beat either hands-down though, so unless you have it disabled for some reason, it’s almost always going to be the best choice for performance reasons. This needs support in the kernel which is enabled by default on sys-kernel/gentoo-kernel and sys-kernel/gentoo-kernel-bin, and support in QEMU which is enabled with the io-uring USE flag.
You’re not using thinly-provisioned storage, a disk image, or an SSD, so you do not want to expose discard functionality to the guest. Best case exposing this does nothing. Worst case (which is what you will usually see with Windows for this specific setting) it will result in a bunch of pointless IO requests being issued by the guest to discard regions it does not need and will change how the guest system handles IO scheduling.
Enabling ATS for VirtIO devices is another ‘you should usually do this’ thing. It’s not strictly needed unless you’re giving the VM an IOMMU, but some guests behave better if it’s on regardless of whether there is an IOMMU or not.

This may not get you better performance with VirtIO than SATA, but it should narrow the gap significantly.
However, the biggest recommendation I can make is to not use direct passthrough the way you are using it. Either pass through a full disk, or use a disk image in a host-side filesystem. Never ‘share’ a storage device with a non-zero seek latency like this. The guest’s IO scheduling (or lack thereof in some cases) will tend to fight with any host-side IO scheduling on the same block device, and you will also be stuck sharing bandwidth in ways that neither system is well designed for. Passing through the full device will get rid of most of that issue, and using a disk image on a host-side filesystem will usually play much nicer with the IO scheduler.

You hardly want writethrough most kind of drive that you'd use as a system drive. What one usually wants would be none.

@TomYan Speaking from experience, none WILL tank write performance in a majority of cases, and will usually have significant negative side-effects for read performance as well. Direct IO on Linux has horrendous performance in almost all cases, end of story, and none will use direct IO. The supposed advantage is that it limits host-side page cache usage, which is great if you’re truly memory constrained and the guest is not a primary workload for the system, but doesn’t really get you any benefit otherwise.

Well, according to my experience, when you pass a block device (full drive or not) to a Windows VM, declaring that it has no writeback cache (i.e., cache.writeback=off, which is "a part of" cache=writethrough) always lead to awful performance, while enabling host page cache (cache.direct=on) would mostly give you fake good performance (unrealistic benchmark performance but frequent system stutters/freezes). (The story with image file could have different though.)
